# External stylesheet being applied to all components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I have a parent component in which there are multiple child components. I have included an external stylesheet in one of my child component using the following code :

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.lightningSLDS + '/assets/styles/salesforce- 
lightning-design-system.min.css'}"/>
```

This style sheet is overwriting styles of the component in which it is included as well as the other child components of the parent. I do not want to apply the css to the elements of the other components. Is there any work around possible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to isolate the child components from the parent component's CSS. This feature is what allows the Lightning Design System to work in the first place. The best you can do is put them outside of the SLDS scope, which may very well mean that you won't be able to have them as actual child components.

Comment: I have added the resource in one of my childs and the css is being applied to the other childs as well. How can i put them outside of the slds scope?

Comment: @Rahul We'd need to see your code to see if/how we can help you isolate the CSS. Also, using the default SLDS build probably would affect the entire page, you'd need to use the [custom build tool](https://tools.lightningdesignsystem.com/css-customizer) to define a proper scope.